# Animation on mouse event on the scene

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

```
scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override     
    public void handle(MouseEvent me){
        Circle circle = new Circle(10, 20,50);
        circle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        root.getChildren().add(circle);
        animation = ParallelTransitionBuilder.create()
        .node(circle)
        .children(
            TranslateTransitionBuilder.create()
                .duration(Duration.seconds(2))
                .fromX(me.getSceneX())
                .toX(me.getSceneX()+10)
                .build()

        )
        .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
        //.autoReverse(true)
        .build();      
    }

    public void play() {
    animation.play();
}

//public void stop() {
//animation.stop()
```

I am trying to let the `circle move` when I `mouse click` on the scene. Its not happening !

I am not sure if the sequence is wrong i.e. adding objects to the root before animation starts ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few edits to your code and it seems to work for me

```
scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override     
        public void handle(MouseEvent me){
            Circle circle = new Circle(10, 20,50);
            circle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            root.getChildren().add(circle);
            Animation animation = ParallelTransitionBuilder.create()
            .node(circle)
            .children(
                TranslateTransitionBuilder.create()
                    .duration(Duration.seconds(2))
                    .fromX(me.getSceneX())
                    .toX(me.getSceneX()+10)
                    .build()

            )
            .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
            .autoReverse(true)
            .build();
            animation.play();
       }
});
```

Though, what I still don't get is the purpose of your

```
public void play() {
    animation.play();
}
```

and where are you calling it !

Comment: thanks! works great. I am new to JavaFx, I would like to know the purpose of play and stop methods as I am learning from ensemble.